# Binding aura:attribute to dynamic aura:inputText component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I'm trying to bind the aura:attribute 'newAccount' name field to dynamically created component aura:inputText field, code below:

MyComponent.cmp

```
<aura:component>
     <aura:attribute name="newAccount" type="Account"
            default="{'sobjectType':'Account', 'Name':'My New Account'}"/>
     <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.renderLayout}"/>

     <div class="container">
        {!v.body}
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

MyComponentController.js

```
({
       renderLayout: function(component, event, helper){
            var thenewAccount = component.get('v.newAccount');

            $A.createComponent(
                "ui:inputText",
                {
                    "aura:Id":"accountName",
                    "class": "form-control",
                    "value": "{!v.newAccount.Name}",
                    "label": "Account Name"                
                },
                function(newItem){
                    //Add the new input to the body array
                    if (component.isValid()) {
                        var body = component.get("v.body");
                        body.push(newItem);
                        component.set("v.body", body);
                    }
                }
            );
      }
})
```

But unfortunately, the binding is not working as expected when I create input field dynamically. Is there something wrong with my code, Is there any code change I can do to make it work?

*Edited:*

Updated component 'renderLayout' invocation as @crmprogdev suggested. I missed it initially but still the input field is being generated but the binding is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything in your component that calls your handler to create the dynamic component. I'd expect to see a line inside your component that looks something like this:

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.renderLayout}"/>
```

Comment: @crmpgordev updated my code above, but still not working.

Comment: The issue may be that you have `{!v.body}` nested inside a `<div>`. Try it without the `<div>` to see if it renders. If it does, you can add the `<div>` or the class itself to your mark-up in the creation code.

Comment: I tried it but didn't work. I guess I've to go back old way using visualforce pages and apex dynamicity.

And I guess I've to wait until lightning gets mature :(

Comment: Have you tried using `debugger;` and `console.log();` statements to put it into debug mode and walk it through each statement to see where any errors might be occurring? I suspect there may be an issue with your default attribute definition. Trying to pass `sObjectType` along with `Name` might be the source of the problem. I think only `Name` should have a default since you've already defined type as Account..